# Which SQL type should I use to input the value 4.865472349

Tags: php, mysql, sql, types

PHP runs a script that correctly calculates a value.  When I echo that value out it comes out as 4.865472349

Then a simple update script is used to enter the value into my database.

```
$query = "UPDATE members
     SET rating = $r 
     WHERE username = '$username'";
mysql_query($query);
```

When I do this, the value that is entered into the database is 5.

If I replace $r in the previous formula with 4.865472349 directly, it produces the same result.

Clearly this is because my SQL type was set to "integer"

But Im not sure what to change it to in order to fix this issue.  Any help?

Comment: What database are you using? What is your allowed range of values? What precision do you need?

Comment: Added mysql tag because of the `mysql_query` line.

Answer (score 3):

You probably should use [DOUBLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/floating-point-types.html). It has the same precision and range as floating point numbers in PHP (in most configurations).

To switch the type using PHPMyAdmin:

1. Click on the table
2. Click on structure
3. Click on Change (the pencil icon) beside rating
4. Under "Type" select the option "DOUBLE"
5. Hit Save

Comment: I'd use decimal so you don't have issues with Floating Point arithmatic later on.

Comment: +1.  DOUBLE is the way to go, as long as you aren't concerned with decimal approximations.  If you need precise decimal values, with no approximations, and you have a bounded range for maximum value, so you can live within a given SCALE and PRECISION, then `DECIMAL` is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the same precision as 4.865472349, you can use DECIMAL(10,9)

Reference

> For example, a DECIMAL(18,9) column has nine digits on either side of the decimal point, so the integer part and the fractional part each require 4 bytes. A DECIMAL(20,6) column has fourteen integer digits and six fractional digits. The integer digits require four bytes for nine of the digits and 3 bytes for the remaining five digits. The six fractional digits require 3 bytes.

Assuming you are using MySql

Comment: +1. DECIMAL type is the way to go, if you have a bounded range (maximum value), and can live with a specified range for SCALE and PRECISION. Otherwise, a DOUBLE will give a much larger range, but with some imprecision (approximations) in storing and retrieving decimal values.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the column type in the database to be able to hold more than just an integer.

```
ALTER TABLE members
CHANGE rating rating float(10,9);
```

Comment: Any advice on doing this in phpmyadmin

Comment: select the database and find the sql column and copy, paste, execute. There is a gui way of doing to too. Probably something like edit table and change the column type from INT to float(10,9)

Answer (score 0):

You can use float, double or decimal depending on the numbers you'll be storing. I would say float is good enough.